# How to calculate total average power (in dBm) of a distorted voltage signal from power spectral density using scipy.signal.welch?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am new to signal processing. I have time and voltage data of a signal that is a distorted sine wave and I want to calculate the total average power of the signal given a load of 50 Ohms. I do the following:

```
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy.signal

R=50
datat= interp1d(data_t.iloc[:,0], data_t.iloc[:,1]) #to evenly space voltage data in time
N=10000 #no. of points
T=(max(data_t.iloc[:,0])-min(data_t.iloc[:,0]))/N #sampling interval
x=np.linspace(min(data_t.iloc[:,0]),max(data_t.iloc[:,0]),N) #evenly spaced time
powerdBm = 10*np.log10((datat(x)**2)/R)+30 #power(t) in dBm by v^2/R

fs=1/T
psd_f, psd_mag = scipy.signal.welch(powerdBm, fs=fs)
df_welch = psd_f[1] - psd_f[0]
P_tot = np.sum(psd_mag) * df_welch #integrating the power spectral density
print("P_welch=",P_tot)
```

The total power I get (P_tot) is not the correct value I expect from the voltage signal. I am not sure I am calculating the power correctly here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: What value did you get?  What value did you expect?  What do you mean by "distorted".